# Convergence of maximum of a countable infinite set of sequences of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $X_{g_1}^1,\ldots,X_{g_G}^G$ be sequences of random variables, where $g_1,\ldots,g_G\rightarrow \infty$ and $G\rightarrow \infty$. The sequences are independent across superscript ($G$). If $X_{g_1}^1\to x_1, \ldots, X_{g_G}^G \to x_G$ in probability, where $x_1,\ldots,x_G<\infty$ for all finite $G$. Can we say something like
$$
\max_{g_i \in \{g_1,\ldots,g_G\}} X_{g_i}^i \to  x_{g_i}
$$
in probability as $G\rightarrow \infty$.

The above will be true if $k$ is fiinite dimension where we can apply continuous mapping theorem (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322464/convergence-of-maximum-of-sequences-of-random-variables)).

Comment: Did you consider the case of constant random variables?

Comment: The question should be clarified by using notation $k_n$, if $k$ is indeed a function of $n$.  Then, you would also need to clarify what is meant by a limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ "converging to" the expression $\max_{i \in \{1, ..., k_n\}} x_i$, *which is an expression that still depends on $n$*.

Comment: @Michael I have edited the question

Comment: Are $x_1,x_2,...$ constants or random variables?  And how is $x_{g_i}$ defined on the RHS?  Would it be correct to interpret what you are asking for as $\lim_{G \rightarrow \infty} \max_{i \in \{1,...,G\}} X_{g_i}^i = \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} x_{g_i}$ (in probability)?

Comment: I think you want to ask a question about doubly-indexed random variables $X_i^n$ for $i,n\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. You are assuming for each positive integer $n$ that $X_i^n$ converges in probability to a given real number $x_n$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$.  Then you have a question about how either $\max_{i \in \{1, ..., n\}}\{X_i^n\}$ or $\max_{i\in \{1, ..., n\}}\{X_i^i\}$ behaves as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  A possibly illuminating example might be a deterministic case $$X_i^n=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mbox{if $i=n$}\\ 0 & \mbox{else}\end{array}\right.$$ for which $x_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. That seems correct but $n$ and $i$ are not affecting each other though.

Comment: Yes, your notation $X_{g_1}^1$ is confusing since it is not clear why you call the subscript $g_1$ and not simply $i$.